# Creating a bivariate distribution from two independent variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

If you have two random variables that are independent say $X\sim f_X (vars)$ and $Y \sim f_Y (vars)$.

Is this a way to produce a bivariate distribution $f_{(X,Y)}$?

$f_{(X,Y)} = p(X=x \cap Y=y) = p(x) \times p(y) = f_X(x)\times f_Y(y)$.

Does this hold for the case of integrals as well in the continuous case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the joint *cumulative distribution function* $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$, that is, the probability that $X\le x$ and $Y\le y$, is the product of the individual cdf $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ have *continuous* distributions with density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, then the joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the product of the individual density functions.

The *discrete* case is as you described it.

Comment: I assume it works for the pmf as well, which is what I was implying vaguely above

Comment: I have added a couple of lines about the pmf (discrete case) and pdf (continuous case).